# Using do.call() in the body of a function not working

Tags: r, function

Currently I have the following working piece of code:

```
my_func <- function(form, char_vars, values) {
  ext_char_vars <- c(char_vars, "x")
  arglist <- lapply(ext_char_vars, function(x) NULL)
  f <- as.function(append(setNames(arglist, ext_char_vars), quote({})))
  deriv(form, char_vars, f)
}

f1 <- my_func(y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, c("a0", "a1", "a2"))

grad <- attr(f1(a0 = 1, a1 = 2, a2 = 1.5, x = 3), "gradient")
```

I would like to have it all together and have it return a single parameter function. I hoped that the following code would achieve that and give the same final result, but it doesn't:

```
    my_func <- function(form, char_vars, values) {
      ext_char_vars <- c(char_vars, "x")
      arglist <- lapply(ext_char_vars, function(x) NULL)
      f <- as.function(append(setNames(arglist, ext_char_vars), quote({})))
      f1 <- deriv(form, char_vars, f)
      f2 <- function(x_val){
        attr( do.call(f1, as.list(values, x_val)), "gradient")
      }
      return(f2)
    }


f1 <- my_func(y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, c("a0", "a1", "a2"), c(1, 2, 1.5))


f1(3)
```

Could anyone help me find out what I did wrong or if I should use a different approach?

Many thanks,

Comment: write `f2` this way: `f2 <- function(x_val){ attr( do.call(f1, as.list(c(values, x_val))), "gradient") }` inside `my_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
my_func <- function(form, char_vars, values) {
  ext_char_vars <- c(char_vars, "x")
  arglist <- lapply(ext_char_vars, function(x) NULL)
  f <- as.function(append(setNames(arglist, ext_char_vars), quote({})))
  f1 <- deriv(form, char_vars, f)
  f2 <- function(x_val) {
    attr(do.call(f1, as.list(c(values, x_val)), "gradient")
  }
  return(f2)
}
f1 <- my_func(y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, c("a0", "a1", "a2"), values=c(1, 2, 1.5))

f1(3)
# a0 a1 a2
# [1,]  1  3  9
```

*Explanation:*

You want the args in list form, so you simply want to `c`oncatenate `values` and `x_val` and convert it `as.list`. Without `c` `as.list` ignores the second argument.

```
as.list(c(values, x_val))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1.5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3
```

Think about it when you calculate the mean value of two objects, it's quite similar.

```
mean(10, 15)
# [1] 10

mean(c(10, 15))
# [1] 12.5
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't notice that. I do not need the dot-dot-dot operator on function f2 though, do I?

Comment: @Kezrael I added an example with `mean` that should make it clear. No, sorry you won't need `...`, just edited it.

Comment: ok, now I see it clearly. It's been tricky to learn and come around some things to write the function the way I want that it seems I overlooked the basics. Thanks